# IE8 shows leftovers from original background which should be transparent

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

IE8 shows leftovers from original background which should be transparent

```
<img src="png.png" />

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
     $(function(){
             $('a').click(function(){
                 $('img').fadeIn(800);
                 });
             });
 </script>
```

[link to example](http://liza.umcs.lublin.pl/~ppiechnik/test.html)

Of course in other browsers picture is displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

That's seems like a bug, and is probably not fixable. So I suggest you use another image.